# MATLAB: curl+meshgrid in two and three dimensions

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with `MATLAB R2011b curl` and `meshgrid` functions.
I have to compute the `curl` of a `2D` velocity `field (U,V)` defined on a `(2D)` grid.

My grid is given by `2 vectors,` `xm` and `ym`, with different size and non uniform spacing.

Basically

```
size(xm)=size_x
size(ym)=size_y
size(U)=(size_x,size_y)
size(V)=(size_x,size_y)
```

Now I have to compute the curl of the `field (U,V)`. So I do:

```
[Mxm,Mym]=meshgrid(xm,ym);
[curl,omega]=curl(Mxm,Mym,transpose(U),transpose(V));
```

as by `curl` function definition.

Here I hate `MATLAB`, since I have to transpose `U` and `V`.

What if now things change and I have to do it in three dimensions?
I have one more grid vector `zm` for the third direction.
In my case, for some deadly reason, my velocity field is `(U,V,W)`:

```
size(xm)=size_x
size(ym)=size_y
size(zm)=size_z
size(U)=(size_x,size_y,size_z)
size(V)=(size_x,size_y,size_z)
```

Questions:

1) How can I compute the curl of such 3D stuff? I cannot perform a some kind of transposition.

2) How can I avoid the transposition in 2D?

Many thanks.

UPDATE:

As from suggested by the users commenting this post, I switched to `ndgrid` function to build by mesh:

```
[Mxm,Mym]=ndgrid(xm,ym);
[curl,omega]=curl(Mxm,Mym,U,V);
```

the vectors have correct dimensions, but the resulting curl is full of NaN and Inf. Any clue?

UPDATE2:

Some data I am working with (muuuch reduced version)

```
xm:
 9.766216216216216e-03
 9.855405405405405e-03
 9.944594594594595e-03
 1.003378378378379e-02

ym:
-1.868625000000000e-02
-1.860375000000000e-02
-1.852125000000000e-02

U
 6.487719505906355e+00     6.484595542834822e+00     6.481272513725735e+00
 6.477425806839037e+00     6.473901821157769e+00     6.470151122571268e+00
 6.467458053085517e+00     6.463566151187538e+00     6.459423008027734e+00
 6.457841717053478e+00     6.453616696740410e+00     6.449119373006629e+00

V
 4.236207101112219e-01     4.331423817443223e-01     4.430340743163148e-01
 4.192580815416967e-01     4.284782537255764e-01     4.380387484097269e-01
 4.145086688064563e-01     4.234037796164705e-01     4.326070249871855e-01
 4.094208818538826e-01     4.179700104710450e-01     4.267929343674793e-01
```

The position in space of every **row** of **U** and **V** is given by the corresponding value of **xm**, while every *column* is identified by *ym*

Comment: Don't use `meshgrid` here.  Use **`ndgrid`**.  It prevents you from having to transpose in the first place.

Comment: I don't know about the `curl` function but some points: **(1)** `transpose(U)` can be written `U.'`. **(2)** A possible n-d analogue of transposition is Matlab's [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) function. **(3)** you most likely want [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) rather than `meshgrid` as `meshgrid` switches the first two dimensions (which is probably why you're transposing in the first place) because it's made for plots and images rather than matrices and also `ndgrid` will have no problem with 3 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks guys. ndgrid prevents the transposition, but it yields a NaNing curl field...

Comment: Can you provide sample input and hand worked sample output data? They can be small matrices like *3*-by-*3*...

Comment: It looks like it does want your data in the format of `meshgrid` and not `ndgrid`. Try switching the outputs? `[Mym,Mxm]=ndgrid(xm,ym)`

Comment: I tried it, but the result is different than if i use meshgrid. I remove the transposition and recompute it, matrix dimensions are ok but result is different. I believe that before it was right